# Legend in Highcharts should not pick up colours specified in series data

Tags: javascript, highcharts, legend

My code is as follows :

```
var options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    events: {
      click: $scope.goToPath(link)
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: ""
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['You', 'Average', 'Top Quartile'],
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '14px',
        color: 'grey'
      }
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      colorByPoint: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#000000',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold'
        },
        formatter: $scope.getBarValues()
      }
    }
  },

  series: [{
      showInLegend: true,
      name: 'Planning Sites',
      data: metric1["chart_numbers"],
      colors: ['#3399CC', '#CCCC33', '#686868']
    }, {
      showInLegend: true,
      name: 'Build Out And Implementation',
      data: metric2["chart_numbers"],
      colors: ['#99CBE5', '#E4E599', '#BFBFBF']
    }
  ]
}
```

Here, I want to customize the legend shown so that it does not use the colors specified in the colors array of each of the series element. How can I do that?

I want the legend as follows :

```
Black color - Planning   
Grey color - Build Out
```

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Kc55H/

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each series you can set also `color`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Kc55H/1/